# Database design for 1-1 where one side foreign key references more than one tables?

Tags: sql-server, database

**Background**

I have an application that used to import data from flat files. There was an ImportJob table that contained import job details (job name, job schedule etc) and source file configuration details (file name, file format etc).

Now, I need to add more data sources so that the application can import data from databases, web services etc.

There will always be only one data source per import job.

Current (simplified) table structure -

```
ImportJob - Id, JobName, JobStartTime, SourceFileName, SouceFileDelimiter
```

**Question**
How should I restructure this so that I can add more source types yet still ensure that there will be only one source type per import job? (It's in Sql Server)

I'm considering the following solutions -

1. Add columns for the new source types to the same table and use a "SourceType" field to figure out which columns to get the data from -

   ```
   ImportJob table - Id, JobName, JobStartTime, SourceType, SourceFileName, SourceFileDelimiter, SourceWebServiceLink, SourceWebServiceUserName, SourceDBServer, SourceDBName etc
   ```

   Problem - For any source type, most of the columns will be empty. This table will potentially get very wide (and very empty) as more and more sources are added.
2. Create separate "Source" tables for each source and reference them with a "shared" foreignkey in the ImportJob table -

   ```
   ImportJob table - Id, JobName, JobStartTime, SourceType, SourceId (foregin key)
   SourceFile table - SourceId (primary), SourceFileName, SourceFileDelimiter
   SourceWebService table - SourceId (primary), SourceWebServiceLink, SourceWebServiceUserName
   SourceDB table - SourceId (primary), SourceDBServer, SourceDBName
   ```

   Problem - The app will use the SourceType field in ImportJob to figure out which SourceXXX tables the key belongs to. Also, the relationship between SourceType and SourceId in ImportJob is not enforceable.

Is there any standard/ideal way to model this?

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid. Example one is very simple and easy to understand as long as there are few sources, but eventually you should refactor towards example two. I think I would change example two to mimic “inheritance” like this so the table structure/naming “communicate” the intent:

ImportJob – Id, JobName… Source_Id (FK)

Source – Id (PK), Type

SourceFile – Source_Id (PK/FK), ….

SourceWebService – Source_Id (PK/FK), ….

Or like this:

ImportJob – Id, JobName, Type…

ImportJobSourceFile – ImportJob_Id (PK/FK), ….

ImportJobSourceWebService – ImportJob_Id (PK/FK), ….

It does still not enforce the relationship 100%, but you have a convention that perhaps limits error. If you still want the system to enforce the rules strictly (“one-to-either constraint”), then you should check take a quick briefing for implementing table inheritance in for your database vendor system.